# npm sync-request: NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest'

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api, npm, react-redux

I'm studying about ReactJS and during my research I got stuck in middle of this untraceable issue. The idea is to present information on browser screen fetched from Database. I've chosen WebAPI to serve as a channel for communicating with database. The API implementation is working as expected, I tested it using Postman.

[image: API Result using Postman]

But I'm encountering the subjected error when I try to access API through Reducer (React-Redux implementation), please refer below screenshot.

[image: npm sync-request: NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest']

It seems to me a CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) issue, as both API & ReactJS app running on localhost using different ports, but I'm not sure. In either case, please help me get to the solution.

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: It said, "no 'access-control-allow-origin' header is present on the requested resource.". Seems like, my guess was right.